# Pass dynamic args to DataprocSubmitJobOperator from xcom

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to receive an event from pub/sub and based on the message, it should pass some arguments to my dataproc spark job.

Now job_args in below code is dictionary. I have managed to push job_args  as dictionary to xcom from python callable create_args_from_event, **BUT** the problem is when I try to use xcom_pull in my DAG it returns it as string while the DataprocSubmitJobOperator accepts it as dictionary object. Any way I can use it as created and pushed in xcom?   **The goal is to pull dictionary object from xcom and pass it to DataprocSubmitJobOperator**

I have already tried render_template_as_native_obj=True and difference is that when I print it in another Python callable its **class** comes out to be dictionary but not sure how to use it here

````
dag = DAG(dag_id=dag_id, schedule_interval=None, default_args=default_args,render_template_as_native_obj=True)
with dag:        
    t1 = PubSubPullSensor(task_id='pull-messages',
                              project="projectname",
                              ack_messages=True,
                              max_messages=1,
                              subscription="subscribtionname")

    message = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull() }}"
    t2 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='define_args',
            python_callable=create_args_from_event,
            op_kwargs={'var': message},
            provide_context=True,
    )
    job_args = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='define_args', 
     key='define_args') }}"
    
    submit_job = {
        "reference": {"project_id": v_project_id},
        "placement": {"cluster_name": v_cluster_name},
        "spark_job": job_args["gcs_job"]
    }
    
    
    spark_job_submit = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
            task_id="XXXX",
            job=submit_job,
            location="us-central1",
            gcp_conn_id=v_conn_id,
            project_id=v_project_id
        ) ```


Expected dictionary already created as below

    job_args = {
            "gcs_job": {
                "args": ["--foo=bar", "--foo2=bar2"],
                "jar_file_uris": ["gs://...."],
                "main_class": "com.xyz.something"
            }
        }
````

Comment: The goal is passing job_args with xcom pull to the DataprocSubmitJobOperator ?

Comment: The goal is to pull dictionary object from xcom and pass it to DataprocSubmitJobOperator

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your need, you want passing the job args with `xcom` to the `DataprocSubmitJobOperator`.

In this case, you can create a custom operator that overrides `DataprocSubmitJobOperator`, example :

```py
from typing import Dict, Optional, Union, Sequence, Tuple

from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import DataprocSubmitJobOperator
from google.api_core.gapic_v1.method import _MethodDefault, DEFAULT
from google.api_core.retry import Retry


class CustomDataprocSubmitJobOperator(DataprocSubmitJobOperator):

    def __init__(
            self,
            job: Dict,
            region: str,
            project_id: Optional[str] = None,
            request_id: Optional[str] = None,
            retry: Union[Retry, _MethodDefault] = DEFAULT,
            timeout: Optional[float] = None,
            metadata: Sequence[Tuple[str, str]] = (),
            gcp_conn_id: str = "google_cloud_default",
            impersonation_chain: Optional[Union[str, Sequence[str]]] = None,
            asynchronous: bool = False,
            cancel_on_kill: bool = True,
            wait_timeout: Optional[int] = None) -> None:
        super(CustomDataprocSubmitJobOperator, self) \
            .__init__(
            job=job,
            region=region,
            project_id=project_id,
            request_id=request_id,
            retry=retry,
            timeout=timeout,
            metadata=metadata,
            gcp_conn_id=gcp_conn_id,
            impersonation_chain=impersonation_chain,
            asynchronous=asynchronous,
            cancel_on_kill=cancel_on_kill,
            wait_timeout=wait_timeout)

    def execute(self, context):
        task_instance = context['task_instance']

        # Retrieve job args from xcom pull
        job_args = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='define_args', key='define_args')
       
        # Apply a transformation on job args if needed, maybe String to Dict
        expected_job_args = .......

        # Set the transformed jobs args to the expected field.
        self.job = expected_job_args

        super(CustomDataprocSubmitJobOperator, self).execute(context)
```

Some explanations :

- I created a class called `CustomDataprocSubmitJobOperator` that overrides `DataprocSubmitJobOperator`
- In the `execute` method of the operator, I have access to the current `context`. Via this `context`, I can recover the `job args` params with `xcom pull`
- If it's needed, I can apply a transformation on the `job args` (maybe transform `String` to `Dict`)
- At the end I can set the transformed `job args` to the expected field in the operator, `job` in my example

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you trying to use `{{ task_instance.xcom_pull() }}` outside task instance, so outside of task instance, your `job_args` variable is just a string so using your `job_args["gcs_job"]` wont work.

You can either write a custom operator that inherits from original operator and do some tweaks to read xcom value as Mazlum Tosun proposed or you can create another PythonOperator that will transform your value and push it to xcom so you can read that value in `DataprocSubmitJobOperator`

```
def f_generate_job_args(ti, **kwargs):
    project_id = kwargs['project_id']
    cluster_name = kwargs['cluster_name']

    xcom_results = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='define_args', key='define_args')
    
    submit_job = {
        "reference": {"project_id": project_id},
        "placement": {"cluster_name": cluster_name},
        "spark_job": xcom_results["gcs_job"]
    }

    return submit_job

dag = DAG(dag_id=dag_id, schedule_interval=None, default_args=default_args,render_template_as_native_obj=True)
with dag:        
    t1 = PubSubPullSensor(task_id='pull-messages',
                              project="projectname",
                              ack_messages=True,
                              max_messages=1,
                              subscription="subscribtionname")

    message = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull() }}"
    t2 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='define_args',
            python_callable=create_args_from_event,
            op_kwargs={'var': message},
            provide_context=True,
    )
    

    generate_job_args = PythonOperator(
            task_id='generate_job_args',
            python_callable=f_generate_job_args,
            op_kwargs={'project_id': v_project_id, 'cluster_name': v_cluster_name'}
            )            
    
    spark_job_submit = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
            task_id="XXXX",
            job={{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='generate_job_args')}},
            location="us-central1",
            gcp_conn_id=v_conn_id,
            project_id=v_project_id
        )

    t1 >> t2 >> generate_job_args >> spark_job_submit
```

another option is to create whole submit job dict in your `define_args` task

```
t2 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='define_args',
            python_callable=create_args_from_event,
            op_kwargs={'var': message, 'project_id': v_project_id, 'cluster_name': v_cluster_name'},
            provide_context=True,
    )
```

and in your `create_args_from_event` either create a new key by xcom.push or prepare whole dict, depend on your needs.

then you can easily use

```
spark_job_submit = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
            task_id="XXXX",
            job={{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='define_args', key='my_new_generated_key')}},
            location="us-central1",
            gcp_conn_id=v_conn_id,
            project_id=v_project_id
        )
```

dont forget to set your `render_template_as_native_obj=True`

Comment: Here in your code: job={{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='define_args', key='my_new_generated_key')}} ----- what is ti, Its giving compilation error

Comment: It was just an option number 2. You must define in your `create_args_from_event` function xcom push `my_new_generated_key`. 
Otherwise you can use the first code snippet

Comment: In first code snippet as well -  While writing job={{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='generate_job_args')}}, while creating DataprocSubmitJobOperator

ti is undefined and will be compilation error